# Consuming SignalR on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr, flutter-web, signalr.client

I am new to `Flutter`. I need to consume `SignalR` build and running on `.Net Framework`. For this I followed these 2 sources

[For Flutter Client](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_flutter)

[For SignalR server build on .Net Framework](https://github.com/itorian/Simple-Chat-Application-with-SignalR/tree/master/ChattingApplication)

But I am not able to connect with SingalR

`main.dart` code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:signalr_flutter/signalr_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _signalRStatus = 'Unknown';
  SignalR signalR;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    signalR = SignalR('https://localhost:44359', "Chat",
        hubMethods: ["Send"],
        statusChangeCallback: _onStatusChange,
        hubCallback: _onNewMessage);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('SignalR Plugin Example App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Connection Status: $_signalRStatus\n',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: _buttonTapped, child: Text("Invoke Method")),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.cast_connected),
          onPressed: () async {
            await signalR.connect();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onStatusChange(dynamic status) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _signalRStatus = status as String;
      });
    }
  }

  _onNewMessage(String methodName, dynamic message) {
    print('MethodName = $methodName, Message = $message');
  }

  _buttonTapped() async {
    print("_buttonTapped");
    final res =
        await signalR.invokeMethod<dynamic>("broadcastMessage", arguments: [
      {"name": "Test"},
      {"message": "Test message"}
    ]).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
    });
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('SignalR Method Response: $res'));
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

`SignalR` code and this is working fine in html page

```
namespace TestSignalR
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }

    public class ChatHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Getting below error while click on floatingactionbutton to connect SignalR

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method connectToServer on channel signalR)
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:52884/dart_sdk.js:5345:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:52884/dart_sdk.js:39347:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:52884/dart_sdk.js:39341:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:52884/dart_sdk.js:39173:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:52884/dart_sdk.js:39179:13)
    at http://localhost:52884/dart_sdk.js:34686:9
```

**Please help to resolve this issue or suggest any other working solution.**

Can we communicate with SignalR through Flutter ? if yes then how ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right you are trying this on Flutter Web. On Pub Site of the package its clearly written that this package don't work with Flutter Web yet. That is something I am planning to add in the future but sadly not yet started work.

Comment: thanks for your reply. could you please let us know when are you planning to add support for web as well in package.

Comment: now I am trying this on flutter android but getting error. please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66365805/signalr-in-flutter-getting-error-no-protocol