# SignalR in flutter getting error No Protocol

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr, flutter-android

I am using pub package [signalr_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_flutter) in flutter app and I have [SignalR(build on .Net framework)](https://github.com/itorian/Simple-Chat-Application-with-SignalR/tree/master/ChattingApplication) which is working fine in browser.
But when I am trying to connect SignalR from flutter then getting error

`no protocol: dev.mysignalr.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.3&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D`

dart code snippet

```
// Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    signalR = SignalR('dev.mysignalr.com', "ChatHub",
        hubMethods: ["Send"],
        //headers: hed,
        statusChangeCallback: _onStatusChange,
        hubCallback: _onNewMessage);
  }
```

Comment: Check your connection url, try giving full url with http or https and proper connection port if needed.

Comment: @AyanDas I have tried these combination already but did not work

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error due to incomplete url given, I solved this by using complete url along with http like:

```
signalR = SignalR('http://192.168.0.2:8083', "ChatHub",
          hubMethods: ["ReceiveOne"],
          statusChangeCallback: (status) => print(status),
          hubCallback: (methodName, message) =>
              print('MethodName = $methodName, Message = $message'));
```